# Web scraping with open API on multiple keywords

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, data-science

I am fairly new to Python, just started dabbling into it since few days ago.
I have tried to troubleshoot to the best of my ability but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want.
I have tried the following: `df.iterrows`, `df.iloc`, `df.at`,
and `df.iat`

The error appeared was mainly keyerror when I tried to input index as row.
When I input an integer as row, it works, but for 1 keyword only (since it the value was specified with an index integer).
I want the code to be able to run and loop for each keyword.
Example:
If I have 40 keywords, I want a final result of 4000 rows.
If I have 100 keywords, I want a final result of 10000 rows.

My apologies if my code is messy, unorganised, and ugly.

Here are my project details.
Objective: To scrape a website with multiple keywords for product data

Method: Use the website's open API to extract data.

Process: keyword dataframe > input first keyword into API and extract data > print 100 rows of search results > repeat with the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ... keyword

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thank you.

```
import requests

# Data manipulation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create sample keyword dataframe from dict
data3 = {'part number': [123456, 234567, 345678, 456789], 'search keyword': ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'mango']}

df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data3)
print(df3)

# Input API parameters
for i in df3['search keyword']:
    Shopee_url = 'https://shopee.com.my'
    keyword_search = df3.loc[i, 'Search Keyword']
    headers = {
     'User-Agent': 'Chrome',
     'Referer': '{}search?keyword={}'.format(Shopee_url, keyword_search)
    }
    url = 'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword={}&limit=100&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search'.format(keyword_search)

    # Shopee API request
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers).json()

    # Shopee scraping script
    title_list = []
    min_price_after_discount_list = []
    standard_retail_price_list = []
    shop_location_list = []
    shop_id_list = []
    item_id_list = []
    for item in r['items']:
        title_list.append(item['name'])
        min_price_after_discount_list.append(item['price_min'])
        standard_retail_price_list.append(item['price_min_before_discount'])
        shop_location_list.append(item['shop_location'])
        shop_id_list.append(item['shopid'])
        item_id_list.append(item['itemid'])

# Define a dictionary from web scraped data
data2 = {'Part Number': "123456",
        'Product Name': title_list,
        'Min Price After Discount': min_price_after_discount_list,
        'Extracted Standard Retail Price': standard_retail_price_list,
        'Seller Location': shop_location_list,
        'Seller ID': shop_id_list,
        'Product ID': item_id_list,
        'Product URL': "https://shopee.com.my/product/shopid/itemid/"
       }

# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: Do you want `keyword_search` to have the word itself or the part number?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you should use `print()` to see what you have in variables. And then you would no need to ask question.

Comment: @ezzeddin I'd like to have keyword_search to have the word itself. The part number is just there as an additional column.

Comment: @furas There is no error message. But rather the printed dataframe of data2 was not to my expectation.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the search word at each iteration, you don't need `.loc` because you already loop over the search words with the iterator `i`

```py
keyword_search = i
```

Comment: I tried it as well. But it only calls the final row of search word. At least, that's what happened to my print, that printed 99 rows.

Comment: @bluemango26 you get only final row because you have other mistake in code - you create lists inside `for`-loop so in every loop it creates new empty list and it removes previous content. You should create lists before `for`-loop. OR you should create `data2` in every loop and add this `data2` to some list with all data.

Comment: @furas Thank you very much for the help! Truly a blunder on my end. I have fixed the code and it's working properly now! <3